# Save data from another form to sql

Tags: sql, vb.net, global-variables

Been stuck with this for hours.

I have **5 forms** that has (multiple textbox, checkboxes etc) with data related with each other. Now I want to save all those data (from form1 to 5) to my database with just 1 button **Save** in form5.

ps. I don't want to separate insert queries or make tables to all forms that will mess up the ID's. I already have 5 tables **Applicant_name**, **Address**, **Permit_table**, **Licence_table**
or if not possible How to Insert those Data with all table ID's still the same ex. 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1

Comment: Should i do UPDATE instead of INSERT because row already exist in form 1 to 4 and ill just modify columns?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Could you please show us your table structure, including an example of what data is inserted in each table and which form it came from? (or alternatively, how you would like the data to be inserted)

Comment: Also we need to know what database you are using. SQL Server, Access, MySql or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting solution. I think you need to change your solution, especially your database design. But I can give advices to you;

1. You can solve this problem with Interface or create a base class.
   Your 5 forms inherited from this created base class and set base
   class attributes.
2. The other solution is create an (arraylist,list,array etc..) for
   each form and fill them with information and pass these collections
   to database related class (which button you want to click)